# Does undirected_dfs detect all cycle of graph?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

undirected_dfs is supposed to detect "all" cycles of an undirected graph.
I implement the "back_edge" and "tree_edge" of the visitor and it found only 3 cycles.

The graph is built with:

```
boost::add_vertex(g);  //0
boost::add_vertex(g);   //1
boost::add_vertex(g);   //2
boost::add_vertex(g);   //3
boost::add_vertex(g);   //4

boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
boost::add_edge(0, 4, g);
boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);
boost::add_edge(1, 3, g);
boost::add_edge(2, 3, g);
boost::add_edge(2, 4, g);
```

The graph looks like:[image]
Only 3 of the 6 cycles are discovered:

```
[0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0] Discovered
[1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1] Discovereded
[0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 0]Discover
[0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 0] 
[0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 0]
[0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 0]
```

What do i do wrong in the following code?

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>  
#include <map>      //pair

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/undirected_dfs.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp>            //for named parameter http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/bgl_named_params.html
#include <boost/cstdlib.hpp>                                                    // for exit_success;
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdlib.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>





//template du graph http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,                                //OutEdgeList
    boost::vecS,                                //VertexList
    boost::undirectedS                  //Directed
> Graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::edge_descriptor Edge;



struct detect_loops : public boost::dfs_visitor<>
{
    using colormap = std::map<Graph::vertex_descriptor, boost::default_color_type>;
    colormap vertex_coloring;

    using edgeColorMap = std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, boost::default_color_type>;
    edgeColorMap  edge_coloring;

    template <class Graph>
    void tree_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) {
        std::cout << "tree_edge: " << boost::source(e, g) << " --> " << boost::target(e, g) << std::endl;

        edgeVisited.push(e);
        if (vertexVisited.empty()) {
            vertexVisited.push(boost::source(e, g));
        }
        vertexVisited.push(boost::target(e, g));
    }

    template <class Graph>
    void back_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) {
        Vertex v2;

        std::cout << " Cycle detected with back-edge= " << e << std::endl;
        std::cout << " vertexVisited size= " << vertexVisited.size() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Cycle end= " << boost::target(e, g) << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "vertexVisited.top= " << vertexVisited.top() << std::endl;
        while ( vertexVisited.top() != boost::target(e, g) )
        {
            std::cout << " Cycle middle=" << vertexVisited.top() << std::endl;
            v2 = vertexVisited.top();
            vertexVisited.pop();
        }
        std::cout << "Cycle starting= " << vertexVisited.top() << std::endl;
        vertexVisited.push(v2);
    }

    //interface to the main.
    std::vector<Vertex> GetCycles() const { return Cycle; }

private:
    std::vector<Vertex> Cycle;

    //std::stack<Edge> visited;
    std::stack<Edge> edgeVisited;
    std::stack<Vertex> vertexVisited;
};

Graph make(Graph &g)
{
    boost::add_vertex(g);  //0
    boost::add_vertex(g);   //1
    boost::add_vertex(g);   //2
    boost::add_vertex(g);   //3
    boost::add_vertex(g);   //4

    boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
    boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
    boost::add_edge(0, 4, g);
    boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);
    boost::add_edge(1, 3, g);
    boost::add_edge(2, 3, g);
    boost::add_edge(2, 4, g);

    std::ofstream f("d:\\tmp\\dot\\s13.dot");
    boost::write_graphviz(f, g);
    std::system(  std::string("dot -Tsvg -Grankdir=LR -Nfontsize=24 d:\\tmp\\dot\\s13.dot > d:\\tmp\\dot\\s13.svg").c_str() );
return g;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    Graph g;
    detect_loops vis;

    make(g);

    std::ofstream f("d:\\tmp\\s13.dot"); 
    boost::write_graphviz(f, g);
    std::system(
        std::string("dot -Tsvg -Grankdir=LR -Nfontsize=24 d:\\tmp\\s13.dot > d:\\tmp\\s13.svg").c_str()
        );

    boost::undirected_dfs(g, vis, make_assoc_property_map(vis.vertex_coloring), make_assoc_property_map(vis.edge_coloring));
    std::vector<Vertex> vctr = vis.GetCycles();

    return boost::exit_success;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, notice that any bigger size cycle might be consisted of smaller size cycles. For your case, the smaller size cycles are detected properly. As an example, both `[0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0]` and `[1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1]` are `Discovered` but `[0 1 3 2 0]` is not detected which is the `combination of these two smaller ones`. You can simply create a `method` which gets all your cycles and checks if there is any node in common between them, then it combines all the nodes and returns the `union` new cycle. In both `[0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0]` and `[1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1]`, `1` and `2` are in `common`, so if there is a `path` from `0` to `{1 and 2}` in the first cycle and there is a `path` from `3` to `{1 and 2}` in the second cycle, then there is definitely a `path` from `0` to `3` as well. So it can `return` the `union` of the two cycles as `[0 1 3 2 0]` that has `AT LEAST ONE NODE` in common.

Comment: thank you. Where can i find more code or math on this union ?

Comment: This is similar to Union-Find Algorithm for undirected graphs). You can find the implementation here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find/

Comment: @alvaro562003 just wanted to ask mark the answer as correct one so others can also refer to it. Thanks :)